# calling function in python

Tags: python, sage

guys i am totally new to programming , i have found this code in the net i know it's syntax is correct but i don't know how to call the `SAES_FromStateMatrix` function so please help me 
here is the code

```
 F = GF(2);
 L.<a> = GF(2^4);
 V = L.vector_space();
 VF8 = VectorSpace(F, 8);
 MixColumns_matrix = Matrix(L, [[1,a^2],[a^2,1]]);
 InverseMixColumns_matrix = MixColumns_matrix.inverse();
 SBox_matrix = Matrix(L, 
                      [
                      [       1 + a^3,           a^2,           a + a^3, 1 + a + a^3],
                      [ 1 + a^2 + a^3,             1,               a^3,     1 + a^2],
                      [       a + a^2,             a,                 0,       1 + a],
                      [     a^2 + a^3, a + a^2 + a^3, 1 + a + a^2 + a^3, 1 + a + a^2]
                      ]);
InverseSBox_matrix = Matrix(L,
                      [
                      [   a + a^3,     1 + a^2,       1 + a^3,       1 + a + a^3],
                      [         1, 1 + a + a^2,           a^3, 1 + a + a^2 + a^3],
                      [   a + a^2,           0,             a,             1 + a],
                      [ a^2 + a^3,         a^2, 1 + a^2 + a^3,     a + a^2 + a^3]
                      ]);
RCON = [
VF8([F(0), F(0), F(0), F(0), F(0), F(0), F(0), F(1)]),
VF8([F(0), F(0), F(0), F(0), F(1), F(1), F(0), F(0)])
   ];      
def SAES_ToStateMatrix(block):
    B = block
    S00 = L(V([B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3]]));
    S01 = L(V([B[4], B[5], B[6], B[7]]));
    S10 = L(V([B[8], B[9], B[10], B[11]]));
    S11 = L(V([B[12], B[13], B[14], B[15]]));
    state_matrix = Matrix(L, [[S00,S01],[S10,S11]]);
  return state_matrix;
def SAES_FromStateMatrix(state_matrix):
   output = [];
   for r in xrange(2):
    for c in xrange(2):
        v = V(state_matrix[r,c]);
        for j in xrange(4):
            output.append(Integer(v[j]));
 return output;
```

Comment: `L.<a>` it's not valid Python syntax, AFAIK (line 2)

Comment: I also doubt about the line 3. Although valid, no need to put `;` after every line in Python.

Comment: For the benefit of Python-aware but Sage-inexperienced readers: `L.<a> = GF(2^4)` is valid Sage syntax.  The Sage preparser converts this to `L = GF(Integer(2)**Integer(4), names=('a',)); (a,) = L._first_ngens(1)` behind the scenes.

Comment: Maybe you should read a basic Python tutorial before trying to do more complicated things. The official tutorial shows you how to call functions in its [Informal Introduction](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html). The Sage tutorial has it early in its [Guided Tour](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_help.html#functions-indentation-and-counting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i know it's syntax is correct

No, it's not.

> i don't know how to call the SAES_FromStateMatrix

Just do `SAES_FromStateMatrix(state_matrix)` where `state_matrix` is some matrix.

> i mean how to pass a matrix in functions ... in other meaning SAES_FromStateMatrix(what_is_the_syntax_of_this_parameter)

Use the same syntax as *already exists in the code you posted*. Most of the code you posted is examples of matrices. Alternatively, use a variable which has been assigned a matrix, like `SBox_matrix`.

Comment: i mean how to call matrix

Comment: You don't have a function called `matrix`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i mean how to pass a matrix in functions ... in other meaning  SAES_FromStateMatrix(what_is_the_syntax_of_this_parameter)

Comment: @ranatamer Well, that's a completely different question. Just use the same syntax that exists in the code you posted.

Comment: If you check out the comment by @DSM, you can see this is valid SAGE syntax.

Comment: @SethMMorton If so, it's not python. Not only are the anglebrackets a novelty, the indentation is off.